# Increment (++) and decrement (--) strings in Perl

Tags: perl

With `perl -e '$string="a";print ++$string;'` we get `b`,
 
but with `perl -e '$string="b";print --$string;'` we get `-1`.

So, if we can increment why can't we decrement?

EDITED
"The auto-decrement operator is not magical" by [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

Perl give us lots of facilities, why not this one? This is not criticism, but wouldn't be expected similar behavior for similar operators? Is there any special reason?

Comment: I think your inner quotes need to be double quotes.

Comment: yep, that's in the docs, increment is magical, not decrement (see man perlop, search for Auto-increment)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[perlop(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) explains that this is true, but doesn't give a rationale:

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. [If applicable, and subject to certain constraints,] the increment is done as a string, preserving each character within its range, with carry[...]
>
> The auto-decrement operator is not magical.

The reason you get -1 is because when interpreted as a number, "b" turns into 0 since it has no leading digits (Contrarily, "4b" turns into 4).

Answer (score 9):

There are at least three reasons:

1. because there isn't any great need for it
2. the magic of auto-incrementing has been seen to be faulty, and there is no reason implement auto-decrementing in the same faulty way
3. the magic of auto-incrementing cannot be fixed because p5p doesn't like to break backwards compatibility

Raku (née Perl 6) on the other hand does not suffer from a need for backwards compatibility, and therefore has better behavior for auto-incrementing strings and has auto-decrementing as well.  The ++ and -- operators work by calling the [`succ`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_succ) and [`pred`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_pred) methods on the object they are operating on.

Comment: link is broken now. Can you fix it?

Comment: @EugenKonkov updated the name of the language and changed the link to point to the current docs.

Answer (score 7):

> Perl give us lots of facilities, why not this one?

Because it is not intuitive what values should precede the "lowest" character in range. It may make sense that `"A" + 1` should be `"B"`, and that `"B" + 1` should be `"C"`. And therefore `"B" - 1` should be `"A"`. But what should `"A" - 1` be?

Comment: Why not follow the ASCII table?

Comment: @TLP: Because that wouldn't follow `++`'s lead. If you do `perl -e '$str="z"; print ++$str'` you get `aa`, which definitely doesn't follow `z` in the ASCII table.

Comment: "A"-1 is ambiguous but it could be defined as -1 or any other smart solution. All the others have a logic result!

Comment: probably `"A" - 1 = undef` or zero