# - - not working properly on char in perl

Tags: perl, operator-keyword

Following code is showing different output than expected. 'i' should be the ans.

**Code:**

```
$var = 'i';
$var++;
print $var;
$var--;
print " * ",$var;
```

**Result:**

```
j ***** -1
```

Can anyone please explain behavior? I know i am missing a very silly thing.

Thanks

Comment: `'i' should be the ans.` What does this mean?

Answer (score 7):

The auto-increment operator `++` is "magical", in that it can also increment non-numerical strings. So `i` becomes `j`. The auto-decrement operator `--` does not have this "magic" feature. Therefore the string `j` is converted to a number, which will be `0`, then decremented to `-1`.

This is documented in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If
>   you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used
>   in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the
>   variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and
>   has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern
>   /^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/ , the increment is done as a string, preserving
>   each character within its range, with carry:
>
> ```
> print ++($foo = "99");    # prints "100"
> print ++($foo = "a0");    # prints "a1"
> print ++($foo = "Az");    # prints "Ba"
> print ++($foo = "zz");    # prints "aaa"
> ```
>
> undef is always treated as numeric, and in particular is changed to 0
>   before incrementing (so that a post-increment of an undef value will
>   return 0 rather than undef).
>
> **The auto-decrement operator is not magical.**

Answer (score 5):

There is no type char in perl. 'i' is the same string as "i". The question is why ++ does increase the value of the char. This question has been discussed here: [Increment (++) and decrement (--) strings in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458068/increment-and-decrement-strings-in-perl)

Comment: TL;DR: increment is magic and works on strings; decrement is not, and always treats the scalar as a number.

Comment: @TLP (The tl;dr refers to the *linked* answer, not to *this* answer, which does not contain the information I summarized)